# Disable UITextField keyboard shortcut suggestions

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield, uitextview

Is there a simple way to remove **keyboard shortcut suggestions** from a `UITextField`?

It is possible to remove typing correction with: `[textField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];` however this as no effect on shortcuts.

Affecting the sharedMenuController also does not squash this.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    return  NO;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved this by implementing a `UITextFieldDelegate` method and manually setting the text property of UITextField.

By default in the simulator you can test this behaviour by typing *"omw"* which should suggest *"On my way!"*. The following code will block this. **Note: this does also disable *auto-correction* and *check spelling* which was ok in my case.**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // Pass through backspace and character input
    if (range.length > 0 && [string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:textField.text.length-1];
    } else {
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:string];
    }
    // Return NO to override default UITextField behaviors
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Is there any new default solution for that?

Answer (score 47):

**Objective-C**

```
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

---

**Swift**

```
textField.autocorrectionType = .no
```

---

**Documentation** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html

Answer (score 4):

Use this only

```
  textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UITextField* f = [[UITextField alloc] init];
f.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Matt's solution converted to Swift 5:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
               shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // Pass through backspace and character input
    if (range.length > 0 && string.isEmpty) {
        textField.text?.removeLast()
    } else {
        textField.text?.append(string)
    }
    // Return false to override default UITextField behaviors
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned answer may not work with cut / copy / paste situation. For example on cutting and pasting text in UITextField, the result is not as per default functionality.

Below is a similar approach:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

NSString *textFieldNewText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        // return when something is being cut
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        //set text field text
        textField.text=textFieldNewText;
        range.location=range.location+[string length];
        range.length=0;
        [self selectTextInTextField:textField range:range];
    }
    return NO;
}


//for handling cursor position when setting textfield text through code
- (void)selectTextInTextField:(UITextField *)textField range:(NSRange)range {

    UITextPosition *from = [textField positionFromPosition:[textField beginningOfDocument] offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *to = [textField positionFromPosition:from offset:range.length];
    [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:from toPosition:to]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textField.autocorrectionType = .No
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AutocorrectionType :

[mailTextField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.x or above:

```
textField.autocorrectionType = .no
```